# Voting to close, post belongs on another site. Why is only HR Meta listed

Tags: discussion, voting

Ok, so there are several questions that would do better on other stacks, such as askdifferent, SuperUser, Raspberry Pi, etc.

So why is it that when voting to close a question as off-topic for here, using the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" reason, there is only an option for HR meta?

The most recent question I have come across is [this one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/where-to-obtain-an-expansive-thunderbolt-3-port-expander-suitable-for-mobile-use?noredirect=1#comment11636_6904).

I had suggested in a previous comment that Askdifferent would be a better forum for the question, and upon editing his question OP came to the same conclusion and asked how one would go about getting the question migrated there.

Sure, OP could copy the question into clipboard, and repost over in Askdifferent, but that should not be the only recourse, should it?

Comment: Migration paths are a benefit of site graduation. Until then, migrations need to be performed by moderators.

Comment: @Andy Well, how can one suggest a question be moved.  Yes, there is the flag option, which I get yelled at every time I use it, due to one mod or another saying I am using it for the wrong reason.

Comment: Let's take a step back then. Can you edit in a few questions that you think should be migrated elsewhere? That will help frame the discussion about what should/should not be migrated and the whys associated with that.

Comment: @Andy  Edited in the most recent one, which is actually the one that got me to the point of posting this.  There have been others that I felt would be better off elsewhere, but they just get put on hold, and the OP disappears.

Comment: @NZKshatriya looking at [your flag history](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/4523), you're hardly getting yelled at... there's even some helpful advice here and there

Comment: but yes, while we're still in beta, flags are the way to go. Bear in mind that we won't migrate a question because it might be *better* somewhere else; only if it's off-topic here. We also won't migrate low-quality stuff.

Comment: @ArtOfCode  Meh, I HAD been reprimanded a few times, hence I haven't flagged much since......and voting/editing is so much simpler.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic at Ask Different (and most other StackExchange sites), so it would get closed if it was moved there.

Comment: @vclaw Ah, good to know that it would be off topic over there.  So, now I will just be close voting all build requests and searches for fantasy items  from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Its a beta site. One of the really difficult parts of running a beta site, especially one which covers the "recommendations" scope of things is *setting scope*.

Your example question seems fine here. It *is* a detailed question, covering a (hypothetical) piece of hardware OP wants.

I would change *one line* in this question and its the last one.

As for migrations in general, they should be rare, and for somewhat *exceptional* content. You can't save them all, and there's a better than average chance that a person who asks an OT question here isn't going to ask a stellar question.

We don't typically kick over hardware recommendations questions from SU either.

So, as far as this site goes, just forget about migration until the site's graduated. Reasking on the other site might work *IF* you're very familiar with their scope.